# Perform action based on directory's existence

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, jenkins

I'm writing a shell script in Jenkins pipeline, where if a  specific zip file is available, then proceed with further step. If the zip file does not exist (it may be case that directory structure where that zip files resides is also not available), do nothing.

I've code like following:

```bsh
sh'''
    cd ''' + WORKSPACE + '''/''' + BuildLocation + '''
    var=$(find Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/ -regex "$App.*.zip" 2>/dev/null)
    echo "$var"
    if ! [ -z "$var" ]
    then
        echo "App zip found"
        unzip -o Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/App-*.zip
    fi
'''
```

When the zip file is found, this code works perfectly fine.

But when that zip files does not exist, its parent directory structure also does not exist. Hence `find` results into `No such directory` error. To suppress error, I've used `2>/dev/null`.

With above code, when the zip files does not exist, it generates the following error:

```
+ cd /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/Deployment/Build
+ pwd
/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/Deployment/Build
++ find Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/ -regex '.*.zip'
+ var=
.
.
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
```

How can handle this case where if file exists, perform operations. If does not exist, do nothing.

**NOTE** When the zip file exists, path `Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/` exists. If zip file does not exist, path also does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2>/dev/null` is putting your head in the sand. It doesn't make the danger go away, it just hides it. `find` still exits with the status 1 to signal the error. Jenkins `sh` scripts run with `set -e` enabled, so this stops the shell script immediately.

Test if the directory exists before running `find`.

In the snippet below I made a few other changes:

- Use Jenkins's `dir` instead of `cd`.
- Fix the regex passed to `find -regex` to look for a literal `.` (so as not to match e.g. `wibble.not-a-zip`).
- Simplify the double negative `! [ -z "$var" ]` to `[ -n "$var" ]`.

```
dir(WORKSPACE + '/' + BuildLocation) {
    sh '''
        if [ -d Build/ReleaseKit/Installable ]; then
            var=$(find Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/ -regex "$App.*\\.zip" 2>/dev/null)
            echo "$var"
            if [ -n "$var" ]
            then
                echo "App zip found"
                unzip -o Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/App-*.zip
            fi
    '''
}
```

Since the file apparently needs to be inside the `Installable` directory, and not somewhere deeper in a sub(*)directory, you don't need `find`.

```
dir(WORKSPACE + '/' + BuildLocation) {
    sh '''
        set Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/"$App"*.zip
        if [ -e "$1" ]; then
            echo "App zip found: $1"
            unzip -o "$1"
        fi
    '''
}
```

Instead of testing for the file's existence in sh, you can do it in Groovy, with the [Pipeline utility steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps).

```
dir(WORKSPACE + '/' + BuildLocation) {
    def zips = findFiles glob: "Build/ReleaseKit/Installable/${App}*.zip"
    if (findFiles.length > 0) {
        env.app_zip = zips[0]
        sh 'unzip ${app_zip}'
    }
}
```

(All code snippets untested.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! Most importantly for Groovy's script solution which I was unaware of.